# Why does GEDCOM limit lines to 255 characters?

Tags: gedcom

I'm writing Python code to read and write GEDCOM files, which are text files used to share data among genealogy data programs. The GEDCOM specs say that a line can't exceed 255 characters. I will be importing the data into SQLite which has no restriction on line length. Very technical info on character sets and such is beyond my interest, I just need to get a little insight as to whether I can or cannot ignore the limit. I'm guessing that importing to SQLite, I would just concatenate the broken lines from the GEDCOM file, I don't see how the limit would effect importing to SQLite.

I foresee the need for a little more insight (not a PhD on the topic) so I will know why/if I need to break lines up when writing a GEDCOM file to export data to some unknown genealogy program. The GEDCOM specs just say what the limit is, they don't say why. When I played with Postgresql some years ago I think they had types like VARCHAR(255) so does that mean GEDCOM is just playing it safe in case some program can't store longer strings? I can't imagine the big SQL programs not allowing longer strings if SQLite allows them. I see 255 and 256 all over the place but it's all technical information that I don't think I need, so if I could get a little guide on what limited topic I should even be studying, that would be helpful.

If my above conjecturing is either right or wrong, that would also be helpful to know. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm interested in replacing GEDCOM with something better but I don't know why a GEDCOM replacement should limit line length or not, because I don't know why GEDCOM does it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it really *matters* why. If the `GEDCOM` spec has a limit, you need to honor that limit when writing to a `GEDCOM` file.

Otherwise, you'll find genealogy programs that cannot read the files you create, and it'll be pretty clear where the fault lies in that case :-)

*Especially* since the latest specification has this requirement for readers:

> ***Must not*** accept lines longer than 255 code units, ***must*** reject the file as invalid, with an error message such as "Line is too long. This is not a GEDCOM 5.5.5 file.".

That means compliant reader are *required* to reject files where the lines are too long. What you do in your SQL database is totally up to you since it's likely it'll only be *your* code processing it. But, if you want to create `GEDCOM` files readable by all applications, you should follow the spec.

As an aside, you can actually cater for logical lines *greater* than that physical line limit, simply by using `CONC` (concatenation) records. A related `CONT` (continuation) record is available to insert newlines into logical lines, since physical lines are not permitted to contain those characters.